# GeoServer stack trace when printing map using MapFish 2.1.2

Tags: geoserver, mapfish-print, mapfish-print-2

When I print map, I get the following stack trace. I think it is related with very large capabilities documents but the strange part is the file is already created in a temporary folder of Tomcat but it fails to return it to the user. Could you give me direction on this? The same app works with no problem in another GeoServer with much fewer layers.

```
27 Jul 18:15:02 WARN [wms.capabilities] - org.xml.sax.SAXException
org.geoserver.ows.ClientStreamAbortedException
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXException
org.geoserver.ows.ClientStreamAbortedException
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$TranslatorSupport._chars(TransformerBase.java:827)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$TranslatorSupport.access$100(TransformerBase.java:433)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$TranslatorSupport$DirectBackend.chars(TransformerBase.java:620)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$TranslatorSupport.chars(TransformerBase.java:819)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$TranslatorSupport.element(TransformerBase.java:795)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$TranslatorSupport.element(TransformerBase.java:777)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.handleRootCrsList(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:779)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.handleLayers(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:715)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.handleCapability(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:473)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.encode(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:310)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$XMLReaderSupport.parse(TransformerBase.java:1026)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:659)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:728)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:343)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$Task.run(TransformerBase.java:300)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:133)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:112)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesResponse.write(GetCapabilitiesResponse.java:118)
at org.geoserver.config.CapabilitiesCacheHeadersCallback$RevalidateTagResponse.write(CapabilitiesCacheHeadersCallback.java:143)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1009)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException
org.geoserver.ows.ClientStreamAbortedException
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.characters(ToStream.java:1512)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(ToUnknownStream.java:814)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$TranslatorSupport._chars(TransformerBase.java:825)
... 115 more
Caused by: org.geoserver.ows.ClientStreamAbortedException
at org.geoserver.ows.DispatcherOutputStream.write(DispatcherOutputStream.java:46)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.flushBuffer(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:450)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.write(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:194)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.characters(ToStream.java:1504)
... 117 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeResponse$FlushSafeServletOutputStream.write(FlushSafeResponse.java:58)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:540)
at org.vfny.geoserver.util.PartialBufferedOutputStream2.write(PartialBufferedOutputStream2.java:155)
at org.geoserver.ows.DispatcherOutputStream.write(DispatcherOutputStream.java:44)
... 120 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:124)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
... 129 more
ERROR:  'org.xml.sax.SAXException
org.geoserver.ows.ClientStreamAbortedException'
27 Jul 18:15:02 INFO [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
```

Comment: looks like there is an error in the xml file - try turning logging up and see if that gives more clues

Comment: Which xml file?

Comment: The one geoserver is reading, probably the getcapabilities

Comment: It could be the case but the error message don't show where the problem is. I turned geoserver debug/verbos log but the error message is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from `[print_url]/pdf/create.json` to `[print_url]/pdf/print.pdf` then

```
function download_file(url_to_send) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url_to_send, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = req.response;
        // console.log(req);
        var fileName = 'water_quality_map'; //if you have the fileName header available
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
        load_mask.hide();
    };
    req.onerror = function (ev) {
        load_mask.hide();
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: tr(
                'error_printing',
                'Print Error',
                'Print error dialog title'
            ),
            msg: tr(
                'print_error_message',
                'There is a print error.<br>Please contact the system administrator.',
                'print error message'
            ),
            icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR
        });
    };

    req.send();
}


download_file('[print_url]/pdf/print.pdf' + '?spec=' + json);
```

Or in short:
`window.location = '[print_url]/pdf/print.pdf' + '?spec=' + json` will download the file.

The previous code that didn't work was:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '[print_url]/pdf/create.json',
    // url: 'https://water.geosci.msstate.edu/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf',
    method: 'GET',
    cors: true,
    // async: false,
    params:
        {
            spec: json // for get
        },
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
    // jsonData: json, // for post
    success: function (response) {
        var response_obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        window.location = response_obj.getURL;
        load_mask.hide();
    },
    failure: function () {
        load_mask.hide();
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: tr(
                'error_printing',
                'Print Error',
                'Print error dialog title'
            ),
            msg: tr(
                'print_error_message',
                'There is a print error.<br>Please contact the system administrator.',
                'print error message'
            ),
            icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR
        });
    }

});
```